# Modifying one cell in CellForRowAtIndexPath changes multiple cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array of names that I'm showing via tableview. You can select up to a total of 3 names, and you cannot re-select the same names. To do this I implemented the following code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. When I run the code the names come up fine, but there are multiple red cells with names that I did not select.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [nameSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionNames = [names objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *name = [sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    if ([name isEqualToString: self.name1] || [name isEqualToString: self.name2] || [name isEqualToString: self.name3]) {
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Reading a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548667/uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath-called-more-than-once-for-each-row), they were saying that it's because the cells are being reused - but if this were true, how is the tableview still displaying the correct names in the correct position?

I tried to simplify the code into this, and still to no avail, there were multiple red cells.

```
myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [nameSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionNames = [names objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *name = [sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    if (indexPath == myIP) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I can post a screenshot if needed. Note: The intended names were correctly labeled with red.

Comment: Is this happening when you're scrolling? It looks like you're setting the background to red, but not setting it to whatever it was before (clearColor?) if *was* used for a selected cell but is now being reused for one that is not.

Comment: That is because you are setting the Name for every cell but only setting the background color for `myIP`. When you scroll it will use the previously set background color, unless you assign a new color to it.

Comment: Can you please write what does nameSectionTitles and names objects (real content of it)? Because it seems that the if condition :     if ([name isEqualToString: self.name1] || [name isEqualToString: self.name2] || [name isEqualToString: self.name3]) {
 is true in multiple cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is happening due to cell re-using. When a cell with red background is re-used it'll still be in red background, you are not re-setting it anywhere in your code. You need to put a else case to your if condition used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
if ([name isEqualToString: self.name1] || [name isEqualToString: self.name2] || [name isEqualToString: self.name3])
{
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else
{
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Other stuffs
}
```

Comment: In general every change you make in one if-branch should be reset / changed in every other branch as well.