# Populating tableView with json data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm very new to IOS programming, i just got below code working fine, but i'm not able to know **how control flows here.**

- **Doubts**

1). In viewDidLoad method i called getContactListJSON() method and after i've printed tableID, it's printing empty array why?

2) When and how many times numberOfSectionsInTableView() and tableView(:, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:) executes?

3). In getContactListJSON() method i'm reloading tableView because its already loaded once when and why? and

4). How to display data on tableView in the First load only without using tableView.reloadData()?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableName = [String]()
    var tableID = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getContactListJSON()
        print(tableID)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func getContactListJSON(){
        let urlString = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        let urlEncodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let url = NSURL( string: urlEncodedString!)
        var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, innerError) in
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            let contactsArray = json.arrayValue

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                for contacts in contactsArray
                {
                    let id = contacts["id"].stringValue
                    let name = contacts["name"].stringValue
                    println( "id: \(id) name: \(name)" )
                    self.tableName.append(name)
                    self.tableID.append(id)
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableName.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableID[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers to -

1. You are putting data into table ID asynchronously. Thats why the print statement will get executed(when table ID is empty) and mean while table ID gets filled.
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548780/4933540). Also, if you are more curious then just add print statements in those methods and see how and when they are called.

For 3. and 4. I would suggest to try to do those tasks synchronously and see the change. You will understand yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1). In viewDidLoad method i called getContactListJSON() method and after i've printed tableID, it's printing empty array why?

> Because, when you call `getCotnactsListJSON()` method the result is not received instantly, it takes some time for request to go to server and fetch results. So, this task is performed *Asynchronously*, means all the other events will occur and data will be fetched in the background.
>
> Once *response is received* the *response block* will be executed and Table will be reloaded.
>
> So, So until `getCotnactsListJSON()` fetches response, `print(tableID)` is already executed.

2) When and how many times numberOfSectionsInTableView() and tableView(:, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:) executes?

> It is executed automatically, if there is a table in the View Controller these methods will serve for that table.
>
> When View gets loaded it is called, without any data, once the response received and table reloaded, these methods are called again. Each time you scroll the table these methods gets called due to cell reusability concept.

3). In getContactListJSON() method i'm reloading tableView because its already loaded once when and why? and

> The table is loaded without any data, i.e. `getContactListJSON()` method has not fetched any result. So the table is empty. Once the response is received you have to reload the table to populate it with some data.

4). How to display data on tableView in the First load only without using tableView.reloadData()?

> If you want to display data on the first load, you have define you data in the array i.e. you have to initialize your array with some data.

Try intializing you tableID array as below:

```
var tableID:[String] = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

and comment the method:

```
//getContactListJSON()
```

Comment: the problem was with asynchronous call... thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

**Ans - 1 :**

Your `getContactListJSON()` method make `asynchrounous` network call, i mean it is getting some data from server so it will take some times depends on different parameters. `NSUrlSession` calls it's completion handler after completing network request. so your `tableID` got value after network called completed. But you are printing it on viewdidload so, it have not any value right now thats why it is nil or null

**Ans - 2 :**

`numberofsections and numberofrows` executes once but `cellforrowatindexpath` executes everytime when you scroll also because it's deque the cell (i.e. resue cell) for better perfomance and memory efficiency

**Ans - 3 :**

When you reload tableview it's called all datasource methods again. So, when you git response from server then you need to show that data on tableview. So you need to call reload data when you finally got your all data

**Ans - 4 :**

If your array is ready i mean it have data then you can directly display it. Because you need data to show. So, you have to reload tableview when you got data. For example if you have a static array of data then you can directly display it but if your data comes from server then you have to reload it after retrieving it.

And this is very wide concepts to explains here. so, you should read apple documentation or some tutorials about tableview and it's datasource and delegate methods, asynchronous network call, main thread etc..!

Comment: thanks...i'd been wondering how do they work. Thanks for your help

Comment: you're welcome...! you should accept right answer according to stack overflow guideline so other people with similar issue can got help :)